# Does dartpad not support I/O?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-editor, dart2js, dart-2

Recently I was trying out some code snippets from "Dart For Absolute Beginners" on DartPad.
Specifically:

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:io';

void main() 
{
    int guess;
    Random rand = new Random(); //create a random number generator
    int answer = rand.nextInt(100); //gets a random integer from 0 to 99
    
    do 
    {
        print("Enter your guess:");
        String temp = stdin.readLineSync(); //read in from the keyboard
        guess = int.parse(temp); //convert String to integer
        if (guess < answer)  
        {
            print("Too low!");
        } 
        else if (guess > answer)  
        {
            print("Too high!");
        }
    }
   
    while (guess != answer);
    
    print("You got it!");
}
```

However upon running, it shows the error "Error compiling to JavaScript:
unsupported import: dart:io"

So my question is

Is it that we can't run I/O operations on DartPad and we need a full fledge editor for that ?
or is there something else wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dart:io` library is not supported in DartPad. However you can use [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_dart_online.php) Dart compiler, it supports `dart:io`.

Comment: So, do we have to use desktop editor for that ?

Comment: Hey, I just found an online Dart compiler, I left you a link in the answer.

Comment: the compiler is otherwise great but does not give manual control over NULL safety like DartPad

Comment: If you want null safety control then you should download a desktop editor. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230672/discussion-between-jay-and-andrej).

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [`dart:io` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/dart-io-library.html):

> **Important:** Browser-based apps can't use this library. Only the following can import and use the dart:io library:
>
> - Servers
> - Command-line scripts
> - Flutter mobile apps
> - Flutter desktop apps